# Replace the data being played by pygame's Sound without a pop

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have this program to play sound at a fixed `freq` with the capability to increase the `freq` by pressing the up arrow. However, recalculating the sound data and stopping and restarting the sound introduces a pop I do not want to hear. Is there any way to prevent this popping effect and get a smooth transition?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep  8 14:43:15 2021

@author: Rando Hinn
"""

import numpy
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()


freq = 100
sampleRate = 44100


pygame.freetype.init()

(width, height) = (1280,720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
myfont = pygame.freetype.Font('Ubuntu-Regular.ttf',220)
myfont.antialiased = True

pygame.mixer.init(44100,-16,2,512)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.display.set_caption('Signaaligeneraator')
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.flip()
    running = True
    arr = numpy.array([4096 * numpy.sin(2.0 * numpy.pi * freq * x / sampleRate) for x in range(0, sampleRate)]).astype(numpy.int16)
    arr2 = numpy.c_[arr,arr]
    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr2)
    sound.play(1)
    while running:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))

        unit = "Hz"
        if freq > 1000:
            unit = "Hz"
        myfont.render_to(screen, ((width/2)-(len(str(freq)+" "+unit)*120)/2, (height/2)-120/2), str(freq)+" "+unit, (0, 0, 0))

        pygame.display.flip()
      

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    freq += 10  
                    arr = numpy.array([4096 * numpy.sin(2.0 * numpy.pi * freq * x / sampleRate) for x in range(0, sampleRate)]).astype(numpy.int16)
                
                    arr2 = numpy.c_[arr,arr]
                  
                    sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr2)
                    sound.play(1)
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding (i.e. multiplying) cosine ramps to the sound arrays. This may resolve the issue if it is caused by the signal discontinuity between the sound being on and off. You will want to play around with the ramp duration and adapt it to your sample rate etc.

```
ramp_duration = 1000
ramp = np.cos(np.linspace(0,np.pi/2.,num=ramp_duration))


sound_signal = np.sin(np.linspace(0,100*np.pi,num=10000))

signal2 = sound_signal.copy()
signal2[:1000] *= np.flipud(ramp)
signal2[-1000:] *= ramp
```